# Create a list from selected list items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fiddle here: [my fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/radi8/LxwLf/). What I am trying to do is create a list of items from a separate group of lists. I cannot seem to get a grasp on what I am doing wrong, but here is whats happening:

1. I have a group of lists based on tabular data
2. Each list has the name of the column and a selection checkbox
3. If I select an item, it needs to be added to the selected columns area (vertical list)
4. There are 14 unique tabular items with checkboxes
5. (PROBLEM -->) When I select an item, it gets added 14 times in the selected columns section

code

(html):

I tried ti insert HTML but is not working right. Please look at the fiddle listed above.

(jquery):

```
var dte = // drag table elements
{
init: function() {
    var chkbx = $('.group input[type="checkbox"]:checkbox');
    //var chkbx = $('#accordion');
    for (var i = 0, ii = chkbx.length; i < ii; i++) {
        $(chkbx).bind("click", dte.adjustList);
    }
},

adjustList: function(event) {
    var list = [];
    var str = '';
    var eleval = event.currentTarget.value;
    var eleid = event.currentTarget.id;
    if (eleval == 1) {
        list.push(eleid);
        str = '<li>' + eleid + '</li>';
    }
    $('#vertical ul').append(str);
/*
    //var ele = event.currentTarget.id;
    var allVals = [];
    var str = '';
    //var obj = $("#"+ele);
    var ele = $('#accordion');
    $(obj+': checked').each(function(){
        allVals.push($(this.val()));
        dte.list.push($(this.val()));
        str += '<li>'+$(this.val())+'</li>';
    });
    $('#verticle').text(str);
    alert('List: ' + toString(list));
    */
}
};
dte.init();
```

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deerua/LxwLf/1/

Comment: $('.group input:checkbox') == $('.group input[type="checkbox"]')

Answer (score 2):

```
init: function() {
    $('.group input:checkbox').bind("click", dte.adjustList);
},
```

Comment: This is the first and the best answer. +1

Comment: As always, I am always over thinking the problem. Thanks for all your help. This did the trick

Answer (score 0):

you only need to bind once based on your selector.

```
init: function() {
        var chkbx = $('.group input[type="checkbox"]:checkbox');
        $(chkbx).bind("click", dte.adjustList);
 },
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxwLf/3/)

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your fiddle, I removed the `for loop`. Here is the link [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LxwLf/2/)
You only need to bind the click event once.

Answer (score 0):

You are binding events multiple time. You can do something like this:

```
init:function(){
  $('.group input[type="checkbox"]:checkbox').bind('click',dte.adjustList);
},
```

Edited your fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/emphaticsunshine/tPAmc/